# Preventing Immediate Execution When Saving Job to Agenda in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, agenda

I am using agenda.js with Node, backed by MongoDB, to handle batch jobs. One issue I'm running into with the current syntax I'm using, is scheduling a repeating event, but not having it execute immediately. I am aware of the "skipImmediate: true" flag, but I'm not clear on where I need to apply that in my current configuration, where I use an IIFE:

```
  agenda.define('test job', {
    priority: 'high',
    concurrency: 10
  }, async job => {
    const {
      to
    } = job.attrs.data;
    job.repeatEvery('0 11 * * 1-5', {
      skipImmediate: true
    });
    await send(to);
  });

  function send(to) {
    const today = new Date();
    const target = to;
    const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    console.log(`Emailing to ${target} regarding second job, at ${time}.`);
  }

  (async function () {
    await agenda.start();
    agenda.create('test job', {
      to: 'someone@email.com',
      from: 'sample@email.com'
    }).save();
  })();
};
```

As you can see, I have...

```
{ skipImmediate: true }
```

... in the `repeatEvery` block, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I prevent immediate execution with my current configuration?

Comment: I'm little confused, so you want to run your job Immediately or not?

Comment: I want to define the job and save it to the database, but not have it run until the date/time I explicitly set with `repeatEvery`.

Comment: Am I missing something? According to my code above - that will define a job, and save it to the database. And it will run when the time arrives that I've defined in `repeatEvery`. But what I'm also running into is that the job runs when I I call this file -- rather than only once the `repeatEvery` value arrives. How can I handle this with agenda.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are complicating the task, This might work in your case

```
agenda.define('test job', {
    priority: 'high',
    concurrency: 10
}, async job => {
    const {
        to
    } = job.attrs.data;
    const today = new Date();
    const target = to;
    const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    console.log(`Emailing to ${target} regarding second job, at ${time}.`);
});
```

This is for calling

```
;(async function() {
    const returned = agenda.create('test job', {
        to: 'someone@email.com',
        from: 'sample@email.com'
    })
    await agenda.start();
    await returned.repeatEvery('0 11 * * 1-5', {
        skipImmediate: true
    }).save()
})();
```

What this does is `define` will define what your agenda should do, then you `create` the agenda with `parameters` and start it. It returns the `Job` and you can repeat it using `repeatEvery`

Comment: Thanks - this works! Regarding over-complication, the additional `send()` function was just designed to mimic some other work being done separately.

Comment: OK thats cool! but if you are planing to add the work that is unrelated to the same agenda, prefer making separate agendas. Code might be easier to read and debug :)

Comment: Right, but suppose I need to run some code to gather/format some data before I feed it to a task, then I'd want to do it here. So still one job -- but this represents having to do some predatory work to get the data prepared first. Agenda.js has examples like this in their documentation. See example below...

Comment: `agenda.define('printAnalyticsReport', async job => {
  const users = await User.doSomethingReallyIntensive();
  processUserData(users);
  console.log('I print a report!');
});

agenda.every('15 minutes', 'printAnalyticsReport');`

Comment: Yes in that case you can do it. but a warning, as right now you were calling the `send` function with `await` that will run it in async manner, so if you want to format data before running job make sure it is in `synchronous` manner that way you won't have weird outputs because i'm assuming you want to parse data with every job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use mongoose transactions to avoid immediate executions.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

Start a session

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();

    try{
      agenda.define('test job', {
        priority: 'high',
        concurrency: 10
      }, async job => {
        const {
          to
        } = job.attrs.data;
        job.repeatEvery('0 11 * * 1-5', {
          skipImmediate: true
        });
        await send(to);
      }).session(session);

     function send(to) {
        const today = new Date();
        const target = to;
        const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        console.log(`Emailing to ${target} regarding second job, at ${time}.`);
      }
     async () => {
        await agenda.start();
        agenda.create('test job', {
          to: 'someone@email.com',
          from: 'sample@email.com'
        }).session(session).save();
        await session.commitTransaction();
      };
    } catch (err) {
            await session.abortTransaction();
            throw err;
        } finally {
            session.endSession();
        }
    }
```

try refer [mongoose transaction documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) for further details

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer a built-in Agenda way to handle this. I'm assuming the option must exist, because this seems like a pretty common circumstance --  to want to define and save a job to the db, but not run it until the time value explicitly defined with `repeatEvery`.